# would creating multiple tables instead of single be better in a lot of connections

Tags: sql, sql-optimization

If I'm creating a database which would be used by lot of different users at the same time constantly inserting and retrieving rows, would multiple tables be better? If not speed-wise, would it be better deadlock-wise?

Comment: What are the multiple tables supposed to achieve? How are they meant to be used?

Comment: I need to collect data (varchar) entered by users, insert it into either multiple rows in different column(edit:rows, not columns) for each user and retrieve previous rows if a certain condition satisfies. or i could create a different table for each user. which would be better?

Comment: If you're worried about table locking, I'd suggest you look for a database engine that supports row-level locking

Answer (score 0):

For a better management of concurrent queries...

- use the **InnoDB** engine instead of MyISAM
- if you really have a lot of connections, it could be wise to use **MySQL Cluster**